# I'd like to store image,name,price in one array and if I sort the price value then name and image have to arrange properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am storing those three datas in to one, if user likes to sort the by the price then, everything should be in order. Please help me to show it like that.

```
  imgArr =[[NSArray alloc]init];
    nameArr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    priceArr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Json script that I've used like this.

```
 {
        image = "";
        name = Blue;
        "option_value_id" = 40;
        price = 3;
        "price_prefix" = "+";
        "product_option_value_id" = 3;
        quantity = 300;
        subtract = 0;
        weight = 3;
        "weight_prefix" = "+";
    },
        {
        image = "";
        name = Green;
        "option_value_id" = 41;
        price = 1;
        "price_prefix" = "+";
        "product_option_value_id" = 1;
        quantity = 100;
        subtract = 0;
        weight = 1;
        "weight_prefix" = "+";
    },
        {
        image = "";
        name = Yellow;
        "option_value_id" = 42;
        price = 2;
        "price_prefix" = "+";
        "product_option_value_id" = 2;
        quantity = 200;
        subtract = 1;
        weight = 2;
        "weight_prefix" = "+";
    }
```

Comment: you better made a class for data parsing and made an object , then sorting will could be applied as you need/wanted

Comment: without key how you set values in dictionary ?

Comment: The JSON is invalid, see: [Introducing JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: True that! Data is plural! Sorry, fixing it now.

Comment: see http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/  . beautiful tutorial on it.

Answer (score 3):

Store all these dictionaries in one array and sort this array by any field-

```
-(NSArray *)sortArrayByPrice:(NSArray *)originalArray{
     NSSortDescriptor *sortByPrice = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByPrice];
     NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
     return sortedArray;
 }
```